# Eclipse New Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have tried so far every solution; clean, change the namespace etc. I still cannot get this resolved.

I have created an Android project with API 19 and it creates another project alongside mine called appcompat_7. This project has quite a few erros and one of them is " article_view cannot be resolved or is not a field ".

The following files have the errors;

```
ArticleFragment.java
HeadlinesFragment.java
MainActivity.java
```

All of these files seem to have issues with R.layout.*

I am not sure what would resolve this issue at this point as this is completely new project and I have tried almost every API above 17 and each project has definitely an error that does not get resolved with clean etc. I am using Eclipse Luna and I am sure I was able to install the correct SDK.

As a note: Am I the only one who thinks this IDE for Android is somewhat messy and not friendly at all?

Thank you for any insight.

**Edit:**

I solved the problem by trying API 18 for both compiler and target. It did not create the appcompat_v7 project so I just fixed the dependencies and changed the namespaces. I still think Eclipse is not working well with Android plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same issue few day ago,

I resolved the same issue by updating sdk to latest version 23.0.4. and extras: Android support Repository to rev. 6 Android support Library to rev. 20

first of all open up your Android sdk Manager from eclipse and download all latest sdk updates and extra downloads.

And then after downloading all updates , you have need to use a fresh Eclips editor because your existing eclipse will not let you successfully update from Android sdk tool 20 to 21.0.4 Then just use a fresh eclips editor and set up updated android sdk path in the fresh eclips (the same one you have used in your last eclipse editor , you can find it at Window>> Prefrences >> Android).

Hopefully this will solve your problem.